# Nginx not picking location with longest prefix

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

In this simplified nginx setup, I have two nginx location blocks, one for SSL certificate renewals, and one for fast proxy (for uwsgi/Django ).

When a SSL certificate renewal happens via acme.sh, it places files in `/var/www/example.com/public/.well-known/acme-challenge/` and then tests if they are served up. However the fast proxy (Django) is handling the requests to `/.well-known/acme-challenge/.......` instead of the `location = /\.well-known/acme-challenge/` location block.

How do I tell nginx to use the correct block? If I delete the fast proxy location block, then the `location = /\.well-known/acme-challenge/` block works fine.

Here's the config:

```
server { 
    listen 443 ssl http2; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2; # For IP6 
    server_name www.example.com; 
    charset utf-8; 
    root /var/www/example.com/public; 

    # acme.sh SSL certificate issues
    location /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        include /home/michael/project/conf/uwsgi/params;  
    }
```

The [nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html) say:

> When nginx selects a location block to serve a request it first checks location directives that specify prefixes, remembering location with the longest prefix, and then checks regular expressions. If there is a match with a regular expression, nginx picks this location or, otherwise, it picks the one remembered earlier.

To me `/\.well-known/acme-challenge/` is the longest prefix, so it should "win".

Comment: I'm not an nginx guy, but your location like for ACME has `location =` while the other line is just `location`. Does it work if you remove the `=`?

Comment: @JoelC that was a fair observation, that was left over from various attempts, sadly it doesnt work without the `=`. I could get it to work if I use a regex for the `well-known` part, but I think that would slow down the pattern matching and is uneccessary, and the main point is why is it not working how the docs say, makes me think I am missing something.

Comment: I see online examples don't have the backslash before the period. Maybe that?

Comment: Use `location /.well-known/acme-challenge/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the documentation for the [`location` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)?

> A location can either be defined by a prefix string, or by a regular
> expression. Regular expressions are specified with the preceding “`~*`”
> modifier (for case-insensitive matching), or the “`~`” modifier (for
> case-sensitive matching).
>
> To find location matching a given request,
> nginx first checks locations defined using the prefix strings (prefix
> locations). Among them, the location with the longest matching prefix
> is selected and remembered. Then regular expressions are checked, in
> the order of their appearance in the configuration file. The search of
> regular expressions terminates on the first match, and the
> corresponding configuration is used. If no match with a regular
> expression is found then the configuration of the prefix location
> remembered earlier is used.

Your `location /\.well-known/acme-challenge/` is a prefix string, but you are trying to escape a `.` as it was a regular expression. This does not work.

For URL `https://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/foo`...

```
server { 
    listen 443 ssl http2; 
    server_name www.example.com; 

    # 1. Prefix string, NO MATCH.
    location /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    }

    # 2. Longest matching prefix string.
    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    }

    # 3. First case sensitive regex match.
    location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    }

    # 4. Another case sensitive regex match.
    location ~ ^/\.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    }

    # 5. Matching prefix string, but not the longest.
    location / {
    }
}
```

If you had all these, the regex match #3 would be used, as it is the first matching regex. It would also match with `/any/path/having/.well-known/acme-challenge/in/it` unlike the #4 that matches only at the beginning of the URI path, similar to the prefix string matching.

**TL;DR: #2 & #4 are equivalent and with both you could achieve your goal.**

For completeness, the evaluation order would be:

1. #1 Prefix, no match
2. #2 Prefix, match (length=28)
3. #5 Prefix, match (length=1)
4. #3 Regex, match => chosen

The #4 would not be evaluated. Without #3 & #4, the #2 would win.

Comment: Ah man, thank you so much for explaining it, I just couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong, that makes perfects sense.